# react: fade-in/slide-in animation when render component

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, velocity.js, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm new in React. I have made a small app with a button and a list of image urls. When button is clicked, an image url is added to the list. I render the list of image urls with standard `.map` function.

I would like to make a fast ui animation effect when the image is displayed: a combination of fade-in and slide-in from left. I tried Velocity.js and found the `velocity-react` wrapper. But I can not understand how to use it. The same goes for the 'standard' `velocity-animate` library.

What is best? `velocity-react`, `velocity-animate` or something else? 
And how do I do it?

*JSX*

```
<div className="row">
  {
    this.state.images.map( (image, index) => { return this.renderThumb(image, index); } )
  }
</div>
```

*renderThumb function*

```
renderThumb(image, index) {
  return (
    <div ref="tweetImage" key={`image-${index}`} className="col-xs-3 tweetImage">
      <img className="img-thumbnail" src={image} alt="my pic"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*velocity-react*

I tried  to wrap `<img>` animation opacity from 0 to 1 like this (copied from docs):

```
<VelocityComponent animation={{ opacity: 1 }} duration={ 500 }>
  <img className="img-thumbnail" src={image} alt="my pic"/>
</VelocityComponent
```

I keep getting this error:

*Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object*

---

No luck with `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` either (like suggestions below). Images are shown but without animation:

```
renderThumb(image, index) {
  return (
    <div ref="tweetImage" key={`image-${index}`} className="col-xs-3">
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example">
          <img className="img-thumbnail" src={image} alt="Ole Frank Jensen"/>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**SOLVED:**

I moved `<ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">` outside of the fading component and voilá :-)

*render()*

```
<div className="row">
  <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
    {
      this.state.images.map( (image, index) => { return this.renderThumb(image, index); } )
    }
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
</div>
```

*renderThumb()*

```
renderThumb(image, index) {
  return (
    <div key={`image-${index}`} className="col-xs-3">
      <img className="img-thumbnail" src={image} alt="Ole Frank Jensen"/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: note that you can write
`this.state.images.map( (image, index) => { return this.renderThumb(image, index); } )` 
as
`this.state.images.map( this.renderThumb )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSSTransitionGroup provided by react.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html

a simple todo exammple from the docs

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: ['hello', 'world', 'click', 'me']};
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
  }

  handleAdd() {
    const newItems = this.state.items.concat([
      prompt('Enter some text')
    ]);
    this.setState({items: newItems});
  }

  handleRemove(i) {
    let newItems = this.state.items.slice();
    newItems.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({items: newItems});
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.state.items.map((item, i) => (
      <div key={item} onClick={() => this.handleRemove(i)}>
        {item}
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add Item</button>
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
          {items}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend going with [React CSS Transistion Group](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) module. It provides an  high level animation wrapper for simple animations.

---

### EDIT:

The link will permanently redirect to [Animation Add-Ons](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html)

**ReactTransitionGroup** and **ReactCSSTransitionGroup** have been moved to the [react-transition-group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) package that is maintained by the community.

---

From the docs

```
 .example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Where `example` will be the transistionName for the component that you wish to paint. and `-enter,enter-active,-leave,-leave-active` stand for the corresponding ticks of the animation cycle. These will be added by React internally as class names to the items.

You can use them to achieve the desired effect in question. A small demo [here](https://codepen.io/luciferous/full/NpYKNo/).

*P.S: not sure if this outperforms Velocity.js, havent used that.*

Comment: Sorry, I tried your code and adding 'example' as class name to image and wrapping image in <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example"> but it does not work...

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake from my part.. That should have been `transistionName`. Updated the fiddle as well, to fit your requirement ,used lorem pixel for images. Let me know if t works.:)